# Spring Webflux exception making a request that returns an HTTP status code 204 NO CONTENT

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux

In a Spring project, where I'm using the following library:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and using the following code snippet to make a request:

```
return webClient.get()
                .uri("/user/" + userId+ "/address")
                .headers(headers())
                .retrieve()
                .onStatus(HttpStatus::is4xxClientError, clientResponse -> {
                    throw new BadRequestException("API Client Error");})
                .onStatus(HttpStatus::is5xxServerError, clientResponse -> {
                    throw new InternalServerException("API Internal Server Exception");})
                .onStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT::equals, clientResponse -> Mono.empty())
                .bodyToMono(new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<UserAddressResponse>>() {})
                .block();
```

when making a request that returns an HTTP status code 204 NO CONTENT, I'm receiving the following exception:

```
2023-06-13 09:54:23.965 DEBUG 16168 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Failed to complete request: org.springframework.web.reactive.function.UnsupportedMediaTypeException: Content type 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' not supported for bodyType=java.util.List<com.test.pr.domain.source.UserAddressResponse>
2023-06-13 09:54:23.975 ERROR 16168 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.reactive.function.UnsupportedMediaTypeException: Content type 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' not supported for bodyType=java.util.List<com.test.pr.domain.source.UserAddressResponse>] with root cause
```

How can I improve my code to avoid this exception?